# MySQL NOT IN and NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql

Is the following query

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE field1 NOT LIKE '%a%' AND NOT LIKE '%b%' AND
NOT LIKE '%c%'
```

equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE field1 NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Generally speaking, which is the best way to exclude certain string values in a MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE field1 NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

is the same as this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE field1 != 'a' AND field1 != 'b' AND field1 != 'c'
```

In that way, your two queries are NOT equivalent. Instead of your first query, you could also do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE (field1 REGEXP '[abc]') = 0
```

See the [manual about REGEXP for more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent because the first will match:

```
Mike
Tom
```

As there are no A's, B's and C's in the above words.  but not

```
Apple Cobler
```

Which contains an A, B and C.  The second will match anything except:

```
a
b
c
```

I think your second query (NOT IN) is a better way to EXCLUDE certain strings, provided you don't need to do a wildcard match on the possible values.  Note that a LIKE clause is more expensive in terms of performance because it has to do a direct evaluation on each row, rather than just hitting an index.

Answer (score 0):

No, both the queries are not equivalent.

```
if (field1 = 'abcde')
```

then the first query will ignore this row, because 'abcde' satisfies all the conditions

```
abcde Like '%a%'
abcde Like '%b%'
abcde Like '%c%'
```

However the second query will not ignore the result, because it will fetch all the records where field 1 is not equal to a and b and c.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp